# Unable to find variable : mysql-monitor_username in global_variables table in information_schema database in MySQL

Tags: mysql, information-schema, proxysql

I am trying to perform the initial configuration in proxysql and I found that while doing the Configure monitoring, I am unable to find the variable mysql-monitor_username in the global_variables table. The article says that we need to execute the update statement in the mysql database but I don't see that option existing already and I cannot make changes to the information_schema.global_variables table because basically that's a view.

Can someone please help me here in completing this step?

Reference Link : https://proxysql.com/documentation/ProxySQL-Configuration/

Answer (score 0):

I think that the documentation is unclear. The `mysql-monitor_username` variable is only present in the ProxySQL global variables.

To create the monitor user in on the MySQL cluster, you just need to create the monitor user with the `CREATE USER` statement, e.g:

`CREATE USER monitor@host IDENTIFIED BY password;`

And then you can continue with the documentation by updating the monitor user credentials in ProxySQL with:

```
ProxySQL Admin> UPDATE global_variables SET variable_value='monitor' WHERE variable_name='mysql-monitor_username';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

ProxySQL Admin> UPDATE global_variables SET variable_value='password' WHERE variable_name='mysql-monitor_password';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```